# Where to find spark logs in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to get spark logs from Databricks and to check connection string that is sent to SNowflake. At what path, spark logs can be found?

I already have this tracing option enabled, but do i need to enable some additional logging for spark:

```
sfOptions = {
"sfURL" : "test.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com",
"sfUser" : "user",
"sfPassword" : **********
"sfDatabase" : "db",
"sfSchema" : "sch",
"sfWarehouse" : "wh",
"tracing" : "all",
 }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on where the information will be logged - on drivers only, or on executors as well. If you [navigate to Cluster UI](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/clusters-manage.html), [you'll see two options](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/clusters-manage.html#view-cluster-information-in-the-apache-spark-ui) "Driver Logs" and "Spark UI".  The first one [will give you access to all driver logs for given cluster](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/clusters-manage.html#driver-logs), and you can access executor & driver logs via second item - it's just a standard Spark UI options.

You can also [configure delivery of the logs to DBFS](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#cluster-log-delivery), and in this case you can download them from specified location to local machine for more investigations (for example, via [databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#databricks-cli))